# How to call the API POST method by passing the base64 image with the urlencoded in VB?

Tags: vb.net, api, post, base64

I'm trying to call the API post method by passing the image file (converting into base64 format).
I am able to call successfully in POSTMAN as per below:
[image]

But I'm unable to call in vb code and got the error message.
Below is my code in vb:

```
    Function CallAPI(ByVal URL As String, ByVal Data As String) As String
        Dim dataStream() As Byte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Data)
        Dim request As String = (URL)
        Dim webRequest As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(request)
        webRequest.Method = "POST"
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        webRequest.ContentLength = dataStream.Length
        Dim newStream As Stream = webRequest.GetRequestStream
        ' Send the data.
        newStream.Write(dataStream, 0, dataStream.Length)
        newStream.Close()

        Dim Response As WebResponse = webRequest.GetResponse
        Dim Reader As New StreamReader(Response.GetResponseStream)
        Dim Results As String = Reader.ReadToEnd

        Return Results

    End Function
    
    'Below is the code to convert the image file to base64 format:
    Dim imgBase64 As String = ""
    Dim imgBase64FilePath As String = ""
    imgBase64FilePath = State.ApplicationSettings.WebPath().ToString() + "Photos\" + CStr(Fields.Item("EMPE_ID").Value) + "_" + epFields.GetValue("COMP_CODE").ToString().ToUpper() + ".jpg"
    
    If helper.IsExists(imgBase64FilePath) Then
        imgBase64 = ConvertFileToBase64(imgBase64FilePath)
    End If

    'I call the above function as per below:
    Dim url = "http://" + deviceIP + "/face/create"
    Dim data As String = "pass=" + devicePW + "&personId=" + CStr(Fields.Item("CARD_NO").Value) + "&faceId=" + CStr(Fields.Item("CARD_NO").Value) + "&imgBase64=" + imgBase64
    Dim response As String = CallAPI(url, data)
```

Below is the error response:
**{"code":"2000","msg":"200003, bad base-64","result":1,"success":false}**

May I know which part is wrong?
Please advise me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: So, the problem is a bad Base64, but the method that creates it, `ConvertFileToBase64()`, is the one that's missing. Those string concatenation, using `+` instead of `&`, really don't help the case -- The `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content-type is meant to send an URL-encoded string: it appears that what you're sending is not -- The Streams and `HttpWebResponse` need to be declared with `Using` statements (all disposable).

Comment: @Jimi I already converted the image file to base64 first then call that variable ```imgBase64``` in ```data``` variable. So, that funcation ```ConvertFileToBase64()``` is not missing. And the others points what you mean are to use the ```&``` instead of using ```+```. Then the next thing is to declare the ```Using``` keyword. Am I right?

Comment: What's missing is what `ConvertFileToBase64()` is doing (its code). -- Yes, and URL-Encode the string you're sending; see the related methods of the [HttpUtility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility) or [WebUtility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility) classes.